# default argument value in C

Tags: c

Is it true this is *not* supported?

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115376/default-argument-value-in-c/1115377#1115377): It is **not** supported.

Comment: It is allowed in C++ however.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument).

> In computer programming, a default argument is an argument to a function that a programmer is not required to specify. In most programming languages, functions may take one or more arguments. Usually, each argument must be specified in full (**this is the case in the C programming language**).

(Emphasis mine.)